# Is it possible to determine latest jQuery version using cURL or Socket functions in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, curl

I'm working on my OpenSource project and I'm stucked at this:

> **How can I determine latest jQuery version from jQuery.com or any other CDN using cURL or Socket functions?**

jQuery's official website is full of other content and it seems too hard for me to determine which "string" could be a current version of jQuery.

Thanks everyone for help and assistance!

Answer (score 7):

Just pull in https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery/master/package.json

decode the json and read the version

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery/master/package.json');
$jquery_package = json_decode($json, true);
echo $jquery_package['version']."\n";
```

If you want to get fancy you could also use the github API and pull the [Repo Tag list](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags) and parse it for every version: 
https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/tags

Comment: This is the "Occam's Razor" for my question! Thanks!

Comment: Except it won't work because `https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/package.json` is a web page and not a json object - unless you `git` it first, if you do that, then you can use the json object.

Comment: @Jon my mistake, need to use the RAW url @ https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery/master/package.json I'll update

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos oh!  Very nice, I haven't really used github before so I wasn't aware that it had the  'raw' version like that.  Though, my question now would be, is that considered the latest 'stable' version?  Or including the beta testing as the 'pre' seems to indicate? (Upvote for your answer though, very nice!)

Comment: I wanted to ask the same question as @Jon. I'll stil have to stick to this urL: [link]http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js and strip out the version from first 12 chars, until 17th char. using substr! thanks both!

Comment: I see your point, it is the latest in code but will not necessarily be be the one that is always on CDN. If you want the one that is online being hosted on the CDN then you can either preg_match the comment in the cdn source OR if you want to get fancy you can read the tags from the repository http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags

Answer (score 4):

You could use curl to retrieve `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js` and then preg_match `jQuery v([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)` to pull out the version number...but that seems like quite a bit of extra bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

You could scrape jquery.com, but then you are assuming their layout and markup will always stay consistent which is dangerous. From their home page you can see the latest version by looking in the p tag with the class of jq-version. Any good PHP DOM parser like [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) can help with that.